# Destroying Custom Subscriptions in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model with some observables and I've created custom subscriptions to those observables. I want to NULL out the viewmodel by doing something like `model(null)`.

Will that destroy those custom subscriptions or will I have to manually tear those down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating manual subscriptions against observables inside of your model observable, then you would need to keep references to the individual subscriptions and call `.dispose()` on them yourself.

Comment: Here is a drastically simplified version of what I'm trying to do:http://jsfiddle.net/zero21xxx/4YZHm/.

In this instance, I should hold a reference to the subscription and then dispose of it some way when the destroy gets called?

Comment: .subscribe() returns the actual subscription,  so you can keep a reference to it and call .dispose() on it before nulling out the overall model.

Comment: I thought you only had to call dispose when you wanted to terminate a subscription early, doesn't knockout handle this when the observables are no longer used?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Knockout disposes of computed observables that are used in bindings when their elements are cleaned up by KO (like in a templating or control-flow binding scenario).  Otherwise something like a manual subscription won't be cleaned up automatically.